# How to remove a dead container with a busy dataset

Tags: docker, docker-compose

When I try to remove a service of a docker-compose file, I see the following error:

```
"Error": "container 11b03...: driver \"zfs\" failed to remove root filesystem: exit status 1: \"/sbin/zfs fs destroy -r docker/lib/e8469e7263d03b313...\" => cannot destroy 'docker/lib/e8469e726...': dataset is busy\n",
```

Also I've tried `docker rm -f <container>` with no success!
Please note that I have an additional container when I execute the following:

```
docker-compose ps
```

Answer (score 0):

Before it I try to remove any unused objects from docker and it worked!

```
docker system prune -a
```

But for some containers, it and it's related processes must be removed manually. As [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47965260/659077), I found the process id:

```
grep <container-full-hash-id> /proc/*/mountinfo
```

such as: `/proc/12047/mountinfo...` and then kill it by:

```
kill -9 12047
```

and then remove the continer:

```
docker rm <container-id>
```